# Python SWIG wrapper for c++ on OSX ImportError

Tags: python, c++, opencv, cmake, swig

I've been trying to write a python wrapper for a C++ vision library that's built on top of OpenCV, but have been running into the following error message when I try to import the compiled module in Python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "BGSPy.py", line 21, in <module>
  _BGSPy = swig_import_helper()
File "BGSPy.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
  return importlib.import_module('_BGSPy')
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_BGSPy)
```

Here is the CMakeList.txt that I'm using to build the project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(bgs)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++0x")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99")
#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules)

# compilation mode setup
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
#set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

SET(OpenCV_STATIC OFF)

IF(UNIX)
  # add some standard warnings
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-long-long -Wall -Wextra -Winit-self -Woverloaded-virtual -Wsign-promo -Wno-unused-parameter -pedantic -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-unknown-pragmas)

  # -ansi does not compile with sjn module
  #ADD_DEFINITIONS(-ansi)

  # if you like to have warinings about conversions, e.g. double->int or double->float etc., or float compare
  #ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Wconversion -Wfloat-equal)
endif(UNIX)

if(APPLE)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0042 NEW)
endif()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

if(${OpenCV_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3)
  message (FATAL_ERROR "This branch of BGSLibrary is not compatible with your OpenCV version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
endif()

file(GLOB sources FrameProcessor.cpp PreProcessor.cpp VideoAnalysis.cpp  VideoCapture.cpp)
file(GLOB main Main.cpp)
file(GLOB demo Demo.cpp)
file(GLOB demo2 Demo2.cpp)
file(GLOB bgspy BGSPy.cpp)

list(REMOVE_ITEM sources ${demo} ${demo2} ${bgspy})

file(GLOB_RECURSE analysis package_analysis/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE bgs package_bgs/*.cpp package_bgs/*.c)
file(GLOB_RECURSE bgs_include package_bgs/*.h)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

add_library(bgs SHARED ${sources} ${bgs} ${analysis})
target_link_libraries(bgs ${OpenCV_LIBS})
set_property(TARGET bgs PROPERTY PUBLIC_HEADER ${bgs_include})

add_executable(bgs_bin ${main})
target_link_libraries(bgs_bin ${OpenCV_LIBS} bgs)
set_target_properties(bgs_bin
  PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME bgs)

add_executable(bgs_demo ${demo})
target_link_libraries(bgs_demo ${OpenCV_LIBS} bgs)

add_executable(bgs_demo2 ${demo2})
target_link_libraries(bgs_demo2 ${OpenCV_LIBS} bgs)

set(WRAPPER_PREFIX "BGSPy")

# Swig Module

FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${WRAPPER_PREFIX}.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${WRAPPER_PREFIX}.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(${WRAPPER_PREFIX} python ${WRAPPER_PREFIX}.i ${WRAPPER_PREFIX}.cpp)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(${WRAPPER_PREFIX} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} bgs)

INSTALL(TARGETS bgs
    bgs_bin
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin COMPONENT app
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib COMPONENT runtime
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib COMPONENT runtime
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include/package_bgs COMPONENT dev
  FRAMEWORK DESTINATION "/Library/Frameworks"
)
```

The project builds successfully, but I cannot import the module it generates. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the content of my BGSPy.i file

```
%module BGSPy
%include <std_string.i>
%{
#include "BGSPy.h"
%}

extern int adaptiveSOM(const std::string fName);
```

Comment: Make sure you `.i` file for SWIG has a `%module BGSpy` declaration (no leading underscore), and make sure the compiled extension is named `_BGSpy.pyd` (one leading underscore).  That should make SWIG generate the `init_BGSpy` intialization function correctly.  You haven't shown the `.i` file so I suspect the `%module` statement is incorrect.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I added my .i file above. I'm working on osx (if that makes a difference), but the compiled file takes the name "BGSPy.pyc." Any idea if that's an issue?

Comment: I develop on Windows so I don't know that the output result should look like on OSX.  Sorry.  `.pyc` is just the byte code of the executed `.py` file.